# change the color of seekbar according to the time played html5 video player

Tags: jquery, html, seekbar

i am trying to make my seekbar show another color according to the time played.
this is a html5 player, using input field to show the seekbar.
Thanks

Comment: nothing yet, i am new to this, and looking for answers, but can't find anything about it:)

Comment: are you using custom controls? you're not going to be able to do anything to the default controls the browser provides

Comment: I am using custom controls yes.